# Magento 2 : prevent promo rules to be applied

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.2

I don't want any `Promo/shopping-cart` rules to be applied for some conditions.

> (Eg: When using store credit etc..)

Comment: Can you Provide More Details Indeed @Sachin Agarwal

Comment: You can disable all cart rules, in Marketing/Cart Rules.

Comment: @PranayK Suppose a cart rule provides 20% discount for a product. If a customer uses Store credit to pay for the order, then 20% discount should not be applied.